# Robot VS code IDE setup Error: browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at <some directory location>\chrome-win\chrome.exe

Tags: robotframework

I am completely new to Python and Robot.

I started following instructions at https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/getting_started/testing with the goal of executing one robot test mentioned at https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/examples/insurance.

VS code was already installed, Next was installing Python, Third was to install the Python language server extension in VS code and setting up entries in VS code Settings.json for

`"robot.language-server.python": "C:\\Python310\\python.exe"`

Till this everything is okay. I tried running the test, assuming all what was required was fulfilled.  But the errors are prompting that many things are still missing. And they are not mentioned in the pages mentioned above.

I am stuck at the error :
Error: browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\Browser\wrapper\node_modules\playwright-core.local-browsers\chromium-1045\chrome-win\chrome.exe

The other page on Stackoverflow, which is for PlayWright is suggesting to execute a dotnet command.

Has anybody solved this while running robot test on VS code? Why this come and how to fix?

Thanks,
Nealesh

.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange but after renaming C:/Python310/Lib to C:/Python310/lib , my issue is resolved. The Robot Framework is trying to look for the Chrome.exe in sub folder path under lib directory, but the Python installer has created Lib directory.